# Pretty printing Sympy expression in Tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, python-imaging-library, sympy, pretty-print

Is there a way to pretty print a Sympy expression within a Tkinter window? I tried writing a function that finds the derivative of an expression (obtained from an Entry widget called `Input`) with respect to x and displays it pretty printed on the window, but need help finishing it off:

```
def differentiate():
    expression = Input.get()
    deriv = diff(expression, x)

    #Pretty print deriv on root window
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the `Sympy` documentation to see if it mentions anything about `tkinter` or converting the expression to LaTeX/image?

Comment: SymPy's `pretty` function will give you a string and then you can just display that. If that's not what you mean by "pretty print" in this context then clarify the question.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin By pretty printing, I mean displaying the symbols I've defined in ```Sympy``` using mathematical notation. For example, ```x**2``` will literally be displayed as x² (using a math font).

Comment: Convert the SymPy expression to an image (there are SO questions explaining how to do this) and then display the image.